# how can i change the android seekbar thumb of image within current progress

Tags: android, seekbar, seekbarpreference

i am new to android... i am creating seekbar... i want to change the thumb of image an each and every progress value... but when I move thumb, its change the thumb of image but it went to the beginning of the seek bar. Do anyone have solution to move different thumb of image with seekbar progress?

here my code

```
    final Drawable thumb1 = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.one);
    final Drawable thumb2 = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.two);
    final Drawable thumb3 = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.three);
    final Drawable thumb4 = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.four);



    thumb1.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, thumb1.getIntrinsicWidth(),thumb1.getIntrinsicHeight()));
    thumb2.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, thumb2.getIntrinsicWidth(),thumb2.getIntrinsicHeight()));
    thumb3.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, thumb3.getIntrinsicWidth(),thumb3.getIntrinsicHeight()));
    thumb4.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, thumb4.getIntrinsicWidth(),thumb4.getIntrinsicHeight()));


             seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {


                 if(progress==0){
                    seekbar1.setThumb(thumb1);
                                //  seekbar1.setProgress(0);
                   }
                   else if(progress==1){
                            seekbar1.setThumb(thumb2);
                                //  seekbar1.setProgress(1);
                   }
                   else if(progress==2){
                    seekbar1.setThumb(thumb3);
                            //   seekbar1.setProgress(2);

                   }
                   else if(progress==3){                    
                                seekbar1.setThumb(thumb4);
                               //   seekbar1.setProgress(3);
                   }


            }
```

Answer (score -4):

Follow this guide 
http://javandroidevelop.blogspot.in/2012/09/cool-seekbar-custom-made-by-me.html 
Since you are new I would suggest you not to ask question like that and read  
https://stackoverflow.com/about 
first.

Comment: thanks, i saw the link, its only change the progress image.but i want to change the thumb of image. i know how to change the thumb of image, but when I move thumb,  i can't change the thumb of image in current progress. can you help me. how to solve this problem

Comment: @vignesh, can you tell me how to change the thumb of image